# Typescript: How can I type tuples of unknown size with varying types?

Tags: typescript

*I couldn't find this in the similar questions.*

I'm trying to type a tuple with an unknown number of elements.
I know Typescript 4 added support for Variadic Tuples

I can't wrap my head around it although I read [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html)

The example is plain:

```
function map<S, T, U, Z>(values: [S, T, U], mapper: (s: S, t: T, u: U) => Z): Z {
    return mapper(...values);
}


const v = map([1, 'hello', 3], (s, t, u) => `${s + t + u}`);
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgLYEMAOAeAygGmQBVCBVQgLQD4AKAN3QBswBTAZwC5kBtA4sgLqEMmTCwBOXGp2R8YXEsjBdSASmQBeKsgqquFZAG9gyU8nEsYYcShFjxNAHTOGzdqoDcwAL7A-UJDYYZDpNNCwabgBGQgByAAsWRkYEWMIAZiFkaUIYQjB1LWQAAwASQzZkAGpkYJqwb2LPIA)

This works for 3 elements but not for any (dynamic) number of elements.
How can I type this in a generic way for any number of elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data represents some extension of an array so have a generic like `Elems extends unknown[]` then the trick is to specify `[...Elems]` as the first argument instead of just `Elems` this indicates to typescript it should try to retain any tuple-ness* of the input:

```
function map<Elems extends unknown[],  Z>(values: [...Elems], mapper: (...args: Elems) => Z): Z {
    return mapper(...values);
}


const v = map([1, 'hello', 3], (s, t, u) => `${s + t + u}`);
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgLYEMAOAeAogGwFNUBnZQgDxkIgBMzIBrCBAdwgG0BdAGmWQBaAPgAUAN3T4whEgC5kHAHTKCxErzRZMhAE7yRyxeh0BzOclWkAlMgC8QwVfkDkAb2D9+OwjDA6UGJjaOgbKElIyVgDcwAC+wAlQSCQwyGJ2mpgiHACMfADkABaE+PgI+XwAzBoiJHwwfGA29sgABgAkriSKMAi4FJhINPCSIjYA1MgwPQgAqkG6AMLoJIRjyJNgMwBicBSEtGOxrdFAA))

*when I say it retains tuple-ness this is just a bi-product of how generic resolution works, if I have 2 functions like this:

```
function foo<T               >(arg: T){ return arg; }
function bar<T extends string>(arg: T){ return arg; }
```

calling `foo("a")` will give type `string` but `bar("a")` gives type `"a"`, this is because typescript will get more specific to fit the generic constraint if possible, so while `Elems` is functionally identical to `[...Elems]`, the first is considered an array type and the second is considered a tuple type which is why the generic resolves differently, retaining the tuple-ness.

Comment: Perfect!! I think the `any[]`  threw me off but I understand, although it's `any`, typescript keeps track of the actual types

Comment: And thanks for clarifying how that works with [...Elems] and Typescript

Comment: yeah as the constraint of the generic it should probably be `unknown[]` but it represents the base type, it retains the actual type but validates that it must be assignable to the constraint.

Comment: May you live to be a thousand years old, sir.